# 1987 Yamaha FZ700 headlights not working

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, headlight, wiring, yamaha

I recently bought a 1987 Yamaha fz700, and the owner said the headlights didn't work, and I can't figure out what's wrong. We checked some of the wiring out, and the bulb connectors have no power going into them, on the high, or low beam setting. Also the high beam light doesn't light up on the dash when its in high beam mode. 
Another thing that we can't seem to get working is the turn signals. When they are slides either way, the turn light doesn't light up on the dash, and no power seems to be going to any of the cables in the back. The rear brake light works, but only when the foot brake lever is pressed, not the handlebar one. Fuses were checked and replaced, what else could be wrong? Could it just be some bad wiring from the previous owner?

*Edit:*
There were some extra wires hanging around disconnected in the front of the bike, and when we measured them they were getting about 11v constant voltage, didn't matter if the high/low or turn signals were on.

I'm new to working with motorcycles, but I've had years of experience in wiring, and electronic systems, so I know a few things, but any help, or wiring diagrams could be nice! Thanks

Comment: Also, there were some extra wires hanging around disconnected in the front of the bike, and when we measured them they were getting about 11v constant voltage, didn't matter if the high/low or turn signals were on

Comment: The mount as in the plastic part? Or the whole area behind it? Most of the wiring is in the area behind where the headlights are mounted

Comment: Yeah, upper fairing and all, previous owner replaced the dash I think, might have to check there

Comment: Bump, Found some extra wires in the front, a mix of negative and positive ones, all get constant voltage around 11v None of them switch on or off when the turn signals or hi/low beam light buttons are pressed, all stay at about 11v, could these maybe be for the dashboard lights?

Comment: A small console? Like on the dash? or like the lights in the dash? I think the lights in the dash were missing, no light going to them, except for the neutral and oil light, hi/low beam light, and turn signal light don't light up on the dash either. But I think some wires are most likely for the dash lights, rest i'm unsure, I know there should be two pairs of wires for the front turn signals, but I couldn't find any that work with the turn signals

Comment: Troubleshooting some more, and I found out some people had problems with the flasher relays. Could that be the problem for the turn signal? I'm not hearing any clicking like a relay would make, so it could not be getting power, or it could be broke. I think it looks something like this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/FZ-600-Flasher-Relay-FZ-700-Relay-FZ-750-Relay-41R-71-YAMAHA-EXCELLENT-/191553258986?hash=item2c9976c5ea&vxp=mtr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got a chance to mess around with it and confirmed an answer I found. All the blinker lights have to be connected in order for it to blink. Connected them all and now everything is working with the blinkers!

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search resulted in this. I couldn't find the legend for it but I guess it should be fairly straightforward.
It could be bad wiring, bring out the multi-meter!
**EDIT**
Here's a link to the [COMPLETE SERVICE MANUAL](https://ia902602.us.archive.org/35/items/printermanual-yamaha-fz-750-service-manual/yamahafz750servicemanual_text.pdf) . It's in German, so you may need to use a [translation service](http://translate.google.com) .

[image: FZ700 Wiring]

Comment: Thanks! Its so hard to find a manual for this bike anywhere for free online haha I'll see if I can find anything in the manual to help. And I've had the good old multimeter out! Lol, trying to find out where its going wrong, wish I had some color codes for the wires, but hopefully the manual will have those